# Moment Date related query in mongoose in express.js (getting zero results)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I am using the moment.js date library. My mongoose schema looks like this:

```
profile :{
    user: {
        details:{
            [
                {
                    start:{type: Date},
                    end:{type: Date}
                }
            ]   
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I am writing an aggregate query but it shows no result. The code I have written is given below:

```
let start = moment(req.query.date, "DD-MM-YYYY").startOf('day');
let end = moment(req.query.date, "DD-MM-YYYY").endOf('day');



let profile = await Profile.aggregate([{
    $match:{
        "user.details":{
            $elemMatch:{
        "start":{
                    $gt: start
                },
        "end":{
            $lte: end       
        }
            }

        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
let start = moment(req.query.date, "DD-MM-YYYY").startOf('day').toDate();
let end = moment(req.query.date, "DD-MM-YYYY").endOf('day').toDate();
```